# Would falling (not impact) from the Cliffs of Insanity actually have killed the Man in Black?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology

If you’ve read *The Princess Bride* by William Goldman, you may remember the scene where the kidnappers are taking Buttercup up the Cliffs of Insanity and the Man in Black is climbing up after them.

After they reach the top and let the rope go the Sicilian says that when the Man in Black “[...] will be dead long before he hits the water.  The fall will do it, not the crash”.

The book states that the Cliffs of Insanity are “at least 1,000 feet” tall.  The Man in Black is dangling at 700ft when the Sicilian says he will die from falling.

**Question:**

**Would the falling alone kill the Man in Black and if so *why* would it kill him?**

Comment: No. The act of accelerating towards the ground at 9.8m/s^2 will not kill. It is the sudden deceleration when hitting the ground that will. This seems more story based than anything. I fail to see how there is a worldbuilding question here.

Comment: @Shadowzee It may not be exactly a worldbuilding question. I was interested in if it could really happen. The question may fit better on a book SE site, but I knew there was a reality-check tag here I could use.

Comment: MiB would bang against the rock multiple times on his way down.

Comment: This question is not about world building it is instead about the story in an already built world and would be better ask on [SciFi and Fantasy.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-princess-bride)

Comment: Tens of thousands of skydivers regularly fall from much higher altitudes, and survive the fall perfectly well unless their chutes fail to open.

Comment: Isn't this a physics/biology question? Calculate final speed of falling human, see if that's survivable by humans. Although given this isn't a perfect scenario (it's not a spherical cow in vacuum) there can be changes - e.g., the human can slow down the speed on the way down by catching onto stuff. But it seems like the question ignores that, really, so it's really a physics/biology question.

Comment: His survival is clearly inconceivable.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's that they're no ordinary cliffs, theyre  the cliffs of insanity. He may have meant, metaphorically, that falling even through a short distance of whatever aura, or source of insanity these cliffs hold to cause their namesake would break his mind, which could be considered a kind of death to a man who considers his brain to be his biggest asset.

Comment: Upvoted exclusively for the name

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what precisely is meant by "the fall".

If we are meant to assume that Vizzini is assuming that the Man in Black will be in freefall the whole time, then no, the fall would not kill him; Vizzini is just being characteristically a lot dumber than he thinks he is.

However, that need not be what he means. The cliffs are not completely smooth and shear; as the Man in Black falls, we can therefore reasonably assume that he will bounce off the rocks at least once on the way down before hitting the water. Is that guaranteed to kill him? No; that would just be Vizzini being overconfident. But it certainly could.

Answer (score 1):

The Man in Black would not only avoid the rocks and survive the fall, but would somehow cleverly manage to turn the fall to his advantage and wind up farther *up* the cliff than ever.

He might not even reach the water. He's just that good.